# roundrobin processing of sockets in select system call to prevent starvation

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, round-robin

I am working on an application which connects to a group of servers via sockets TCP/IP.

Some of the servers have a lot of data to send and/or send fastly while some have very less relatively and/or send slowly.

In this scenario to prevent starvation of servers that are sending slowly, does it make sense to round-robin processing of sockets in the select system call

something like,

```
//pseudo code for Round-Robin
    ...
    int start_fd = 0;
    
    while (true) {
        fd_set tempfds;
        FD_ZERO(&tempfds);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < num_servers; ++i) {
            // Calculate the index of the socket descriptor
            // to be checked using round-robin scheduling.
            int index = (i + start_fd) % num_servers;
            int sockfd = sockets[index];
            FD_SET(sockfd, &tempfds);
        }
    
        if (select(maxfd+1, &tempfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("select");
            exit(3);
        }
    
        bool data_processed = false;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < num_servers; ++i) {
            // Calculate the index of the socket descriptor
            // to be checked using round-robin scheduling.
            int index = (i + start_fd) % num_servers;
            int sockfd = sockets[index];
    
            if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &tempfds)) {
                ssize_t n = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
                if (n <= 0) {
                    if (n < 0) perror("recv");
                    close(sockfd);
                    sockets.erase(sockets.begin() + index);
                    num_servers -= 1;
                } else {
                    buffer[n] = '\0';
                    printf("Received from server %d: %s\n", index, buffer);
                    data_processed = true;
                    start_fd = (index + 1) % num_servers;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        if (!data_processed) {
            // If no data was processed this round (i.e., no servers have data available),
            // move on to the next server for the next round.
            start_fd = (start_fd + 1) % num_servers;
        }
    }
    ...
```

> ```
>     //pseudo code for Non-Round-Robin
>     maxFH = N//maximum file handle, say N connections total
> while (true) {    
>     select(call on all fds for reading upto maxFH)
> // after each system call, start checking from the fd at index 0 for read readiness    
>     for (int i=0; i < maxFH; i++)
>     {
>          if filehandleready(fds[i]) process(fds[i]);
>     
>     }
> }
> ```

Please feel free to suggest other ways to handle starvation and fair handling.
Just do not want few of the servers to fall too behind because of my application processing.

Comment: With the question as posed, probably it does, yes.  But have you considered multi-threading your code?  Doing that might be tricky, but it's generally the way to get better performance on modern hardware.

Comment: @PaulSanders lets say i do not want to use multithreading here...how does the round-robin really help here on average over running for long duration vs just doing in same order every time

Comment: Suppose, for example, that requests coming in on a particular socket are arriving quickly enough to monopolise the CPU.  If that happens, you will never move on.

Comment: @PaulSanders how will round robin help here (no multi threading)

Comment: By moving on from the socket that would otherwise monopolise the CPU?  I thought that was your idea all along.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes but we will be looping through all the read ready sockets even without round robin no? So even a slow sender will be read in the next invocations of select call, correct? Just thinking how much help it is to do round robin here on average

Comment: You need to show two code fragments to make it clear what you're driving at - one 'round robin' and one not.

Comment: @PaulSanders updated the two code fragments pseudo code, could you please check

Comment: Thanks for that, now that I see the code I think the 'non-round-robin' will be fine.  As you say, all 'ready' sockets will be processed before next calling `select` so none will be starved.  I probably should have looked at the original code more carefully, sorry about that.  But do consider multi-threading, if you plan to use this code for serious work.

Comment: @PaulSanders updated roundrobin code snippet..do you think in this way it is better than the non-roundrobin one

Comment: No I don't (I thought I already said that)